# How to reverse the order of elements in responsive mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I am creating a responsive web page with an infographic content and I encounter this problem:

The html structure where my problem is,

```
<div class="holder">
    <div class="one card"></div>
    <div class="two card"></div>
    <div class="three card"></div>
</div>
<div class="holder">    
    <div class="three card"></div>    
    <div class="two card"></div>
    <div class="one card"></div>
</div>
```

On viewport above 600px, I want my infographic to display horizontally (each card @display: inline-block) with each layer starts alternately which works fine.

The problem is, if the viewport is less than 600px, I am trying to display the infographic vertically (each card @display: block). with this structure(not alternating):

```
<div class="holder">
    <div class="one card"></div>
    <div class="two card"></div>
    <div class="three card"></div>
</div>
<div class="holder">    
    <div class="one card"></div>
    <div class="two card"></div>
    <div class="three card"></div>
</div>
```

What would be the best way to shift my structure from the first into the second one when the viewport is below 600px?

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/oahrfn0j/1/)

Comment: pure css?? or jquery????

Comment: @C-linkNepal What would be the best way?

Comment: If you can use jquery then it's easily shifted....

Comment: Do they have explicit heights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may reverse the order of the items of the second `.holder` element playing a bit with display: `table` | `table-footer-group` | `table-header-group`.

Try rewriting your media query like so : http://jsfiddle.net/bs5dam2j/

```
@media (max-width: 400px){

    .holder .card { display: block; }

    .holder + .holder { display: table; }
    .holder + .holder .one { display: table-header-group; } 
    .holder + .holder .three { display: table-footer-group; } 

    /* trick to show .one and .three when they are empty */
    .holder + .holder .card:before {
      display: inline-block;
      content: "";
      height: 100px;
      width: 1px;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, i guess i read more about css display table.. I was trying with the js/jquery solution but i found this faster(performance)..And with js i have to write also a script to revert back the structure when viewport is again above 600px.

Answer (score 5):

As a pure CSS solution you could rotate the `.holder` container by `180` degree and then rotate the boxes by `-180` degree to reverse the ordering:

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/oahrfn0j/3/)**

```css
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .card { display: block; }

    .holder + .holder {
        transform: rotate(180deg);
        direction: rtl; /* Fix the horizontally alignment */
    }

    .holder + .holder .card {
        transform: rotate(-180deg);
        direction: ltr;  /* Fix the horizontally alignment */
    }
}
```

It is worth noting that CSS transforms are supported in IE9+.

---

It would be much simple if they all have an explicit `height` and the number of them is fixed so that you can move them visually by `relative` positioning.

```
.card {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

.holder + .holder > :first-child {
    top: 200px;
}

.holder + .holder > :last-child {
    top: -200px;
}
```

Comment: Here is the **[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/oahrfn0j/5/)** of the second approach.

Comment: this is a wicked solution!  :)

Answer (score 0):

For >600px use `.card{ float-left; width: (100 / 3)% }`;
For <600px use `.card{ float: none; display: block; width: 100%; }`

Answer (score 0):

Just change your `.holder` CSS `display:inline-block;` to :

```
.holder{
    float:left;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/oahrfn0j/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

With jquery, you can reverse the order of html like below:

```
$(window).on('resize',function(){
    if($(window).width()<600){
      var div= $('.holder');
      var divItems = div.children('.card');
      div.append(divItems.get().reverse());
    }
}).resize();
```